# Dividir grafica que muestra valores True y False

Tags: python, matplotlib, group-by, sum, plot

Hola a todos tengo este código

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_1=pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\donpi\\Desktop\\Analisis datos\\historico1.xlsx')
```

este es el data frame

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

empiezo un proceso de filtrado para eliminar los datos que no me sirven y llenar los valores que estan como NaN

```
a=(data_1['Tiempo (min)']>3)&(data_1['Energía (KWh)']<1)
data_1[a]
data_2=data_1.drop(data_1[a].index)
b=data_2['Tiempo (min)']>600
data_2[b]
data_3=data_2.drop(data_2[b].index)
c= data_3['Energía (KWh)']<1
data_3[c]
data_8=data_3.drop(data_3[c].index)
filanan=data_4[data_4.isnull().any(1)]
filanan.isnull()
data_9=data_8.drop(4980)
data_9.isnull().sum()
data_10=data_9.fillna(27)
data_10.isnull().sum()
```

agrupo las variables que necesito con groupby y empiezo a filtrar por mes, ya que la grafica que necesito es la suma de la variable tiempo y energía por cada mes del año

```
enero=data_10['Mes']==1
data_10.groupby([enero,'Num Cargador'])['Energía (KWh)','Tiempo 
(min)'].agg('sum')
```

obteniendo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se observa me saca valores True los cuales corresponden a la suma de las dos variables en ese mes, pero también me saca los calores False que son la suma de las mismas variables los 11 meses restantes. Al graficar queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como puedo separar las dos gráficas de forma que solo pueda graficas los que solo aparecen con True.

Gracias

Comment: podrías colocar tu dataframe o los datos que usas para replicar tu ejemplo?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola Crisrian, puse el código que use, y una imagen del data frame. Gracias por la ayuda